# Reset all control on ActiveSheet

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I need to reset all controls on Activesheet (not a userform) to null. 
I tried to loop using ( OLEObject or Controls) but I got :

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

At this line `For Each ctrl In ActiveSheet.OLEObject` . 
 I even tried to use the not recommended `On Error Resume Next`, But it did not help. 
The activesheet only contains two TextBox (ActiveX) and one ComboBox (ActiveX)

```
Sub Reset_All_control_on_ActiveSheet()
    Dim ctrl As OLEObject
     For Each ctrl In ActiveSheet.OLEObject
        ctrl.Value = ""
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the sheet - maybe you have controls that don't support the `value`- property -

Comment: @Ike  ,The activesheet only contains two TextBox (ActiveX) and one ComboBox (ActiveX)

Comment: `ActiveSheet.OLEObject` should be `ActiveSheet.OLEObjectS`. It is the difference between a collection and an object... Then, I am afraid that the error will be moved to the next line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
     'your code...
     For Each ctrl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        ctrl.Object.Value = ""
     Next
```

If you intent to place other oleObjects (in the future) you can condition the code to run only if the objects are of type `TextBox` of `ComboBox`:

```
   For Each ctrl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
     If TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.TextBox Or _
          TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.ComboBox Then 'to exclude other types...
        ctrl.Object.Value = ""
     End If
   Next
```

Comment: @Soma I updated the answer with a version to do it only for the two mentioned controls type. In case that in the future you may add some other types...